# Could not find a RichResponse or SystemIntent in the platform response for agentId:

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have enabled fulfillment. And this is how my index.js file looks like:

```
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

  function welcome(agent) {
    agent.add(`Welcome, I am agent. What is your name?`);
  }

  function fallback(agent) {
    agent.add(`I didn't understand`);
    agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try again?`);
  }
 function funtion_name(agent){
    let x = agent.parameter.self_defined_identity;
    if(x=='something'){
        agent.add('WOW');
     }
   }
    let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
  intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
  intentMap.set('Intent_name',function_name);
  // intentMap.set('your intent name here', yourFunctionHandler);
  // intentMap.set('your intent name here', googleAssistantHandler);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

It works till a value which should invoke 'intent_name' is not the input. On invoking this intent it gives this error:

```
Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse because of invalid platform response: Could not find a RichResponse or SystemIntent in the platform response for agentId: 12628eb5-d7af-48f9-b013-2e1607d77018 and intentId: 622559ad-9408-4e45-ab01-669528b7f227.
```

Please help.

Comment: Is this code syntactically correct? It looks like you're missing a closing bracket in your `function_name` function.

Comment: @NickFelker, that is a typo, excuse me for that. In the actual code the bracket is there.

Comment: Should you have some sort of else condition, for when `x !== 'something'`?